# How to bind property of View to property of class using Flex MATE

Tags: apache-flex, binding, mate

Lately i discovered MATE (for Flex development) and was wondering: how do i bind a property in a view (actually a navigatorcontent component) to another property in a class so that they stay in synchronization (meaning that whenever the property in the class changes the property in the view also changes).

So if we have a view called Target.mxml and a property targertProp how do we bind it to the class called SourceClass with property SourceProp?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Injectors target="{Target}">
   <PropertyInjector targetKey="targertProp" 
                     source="{SourceClass}"
                     sourceKey="SourceProp"/>
</Injectors>
```

Of course SourceProp must be [Bindable]

Comment: Yeah! fiction you 're right! This answers the question (which i should have formulated completely different, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644379/reflect-property-change-from-one-view-into-another-view-using-a-class-as-intermed)

Answer (score 1):

For future use:
fiction has answered the question correctly.

Actually it should have been formulated [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644379/reflect-property-change-from-one-view-into-another-view-using-a-class-as-intermed)!

Answer (score 0):

Read my article below

http://vinothbabu.com/2010/03/21/introduction-to-mate-framework/

on how you use the Injectors Tag to play with. Its a very simple example. Let me if you were looking for something else.

Comment: Could you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644379/reflect-property-change-from-one-view-into-another-view-using-a-class-as-intermed?